# Gvnix: show different controllers on the map

Tags: gvnix

I have an entity Actuaciones, with its controller, and I have created a new controller for the same entity:

```
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.ElectricidadController --backingType ~.domain.Actuacion  --path electricidad
```

The idea is to apply filters on this new controller and then display on the map the data filtered.

I edited the file views/mapa/show.jspx as follows:

```
<layer:entity filterType="auto" id="l_es_ratowrs_geoportal2_domain_Actuacion" path="/electricidad" pk="id" z="user-managed">
        <layer:entity-field field="ubicacion" icon="glyphicon-home" iconLibrary="glyphicon" id="l_es_ratowrs_geoportal2_domain_Actuacion_ubicacion" markerColor="purple" z="8FKc5fLt7SAFzyuwUelU4X7zXuE="/>
    </layer:entity>
```

However, in the map filter I do not get shown the controller "Electricidad", but the "Actuacion".

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.